# Can I call a method which I create in another class in my current class in java?

Tags: java, class, methods

I want to create a program for a simple game. The game has 3 classes:

1. `Player`: contains player details like username, family name and
   last name
2. `Nimsys`: the system containing all the methods for the game
   functions, can have up to 100 players
3. `NimGame`: 1 game is played by 2 players only

Question: I have created the 3 classes but I don't know how to link the classes together. How do I add a player name using `Scanner` and `StringTokenizer` to separate the username, family name and last name? Should my main method be in `NimGame` class? In my code, when I call `NimPlayer.addPlayer()`, it has error message that the method `addPlayer` is undefined for type `NimPlayer`. Please help how to use method `addPlayer`??

So far my code looks like this:

```
public class NimGame 
{
int currentStoneCount, stoneRemovalUpperBound;
private NimPlayer player1, player2;

public static void main (String [] args) 
{
    System.out.println ("Welcome to Nim");
    System.out.println("\n>");

    **NimPlayer.addPlayer();**
}

public class NimPlayer 
{
String userName, givenName, familyName, newFamilyName, newGivenName;
int gamesPlayed, gamesWon, gamesLost;

/*Constructor*/
public NimPlayer (String userName, String givenName, String familyName,
                      String newFamilyName, String newGivenName)
{
    this.userName = userName;
    this.givenName = givenName;
    this.familyName = familyName;
    this.newFamilyName = newFamilyName;
    this.newGivenName = newGivenName;
}
}

import java.util.Scanner;
java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Nimsys 
{
public static void addPlayer()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String [ ] player = new String [100]; //an array of 100 players

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    {
    boolean isInArray = false;
    String NimPlayer = keyboard.next();
    String delimiters = " add player, "; //add player, comma and blank space
    StringTokenizer nameFactory = new StringTokenizer (NimPlayer, delimiters);
    String userName = nameFactory.nextToken();
    String familyName = nameFactory.nextToken();
    String givenName = nameFactory.nextToken();

    if (i>0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                if (player [j].equalsIgnoreCase(userName))
                { 
                    isInArray = true;
                    System.out.println("The player already exists.");
                    System.out.println("\n>");
                }
                else
                {
                    player [j] = NimPlayer;
                    System.out.println("\n>");
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
NimSys.addPlayer();
```

This is badly broken:

```
player [j] = NimPlayer;
```

You might mean

```
player [j] = new NimPlayer( ...,...,... );
```

with all the many (too many?) parameters the NimPlayer constructor expects. But then again, `player` is a `String` array, so you should change this definition.

And why do you think you need 100 players?

Answer (score 0):

In support of what laune said, you can't call

```
NimPlayer.addPlayer();
```

because your addPlayer method is in the class NimSys, not NimPlayer.  And your

```
String [ ] player = new String [100]; //an array of 100 players
```

needs to be of type NimPlayer because it holds NimPlayers, not strings.  And in order to be able to add/edit later, I'd change it to a List:

```
List<NimPlayer> player = new ArrayList<NimPlayer>(); //an array of x amount of players
```

From what I can gather about your code, it seems that the best approach may be to create a constructor with no parameters in your NimPlayer class

```
public NimPlayer(){
}
```

create a new NimPlayer

```
currentPlayer = new NimPlayer();
```

and assign the values like this:

```
currentPlayer.userName = nameFactory.nextToken();
currentPlayer.familyName = nameFactory.nextToken();
currentPlayer.givenName = nameFactory.nextToken();
```

From there you could compare this currentPlayer to all the other NimPlayers in your array by comparing usernames:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < player.size(); j++)
        {
            NimPlayer storedPlayer = player.get(j);
            if (storedPlayer.userName.equalsIgnoreCase(currentPlayer.userName))
            { 
                isInArray = true;
                System.out.println("The player already exists.");
                System.out.println("\n>");
            }
            else
            {
                player.add(currentPlayer);
                System.out.println("\n>");
            }
        }
```